# Pegar todas as palavra entre 2 caracteres

Tags: c#, regex

Texto:
`var texto = "if(true) { {{palavra1}} + {{palavra2}}; }"`

Os únicos caracteres que eu sei que sempre vão existir são `{{` e `}}`.

Eu fiz assim, mas desta forma so pego a primeira palavra:

```
Regex r = new Regex(@"\{\{[^\}]+?\}\}");
Match m = r.Match(texto);
Console.Write(m); 
// Resultado: {{palavra1}}
```

O que desejo:

```
{{palavra1}}
{{palavra2}}
```

Comment: como disse, eu consegui pegar, o problema é pegar as todas que tiver na string

Comment: eu peguei a `{{palavra1}}` somente, preciso da `{{palavra2}}` tambem e de quantas mais houver na string

Comment: @danieltakeshi não se enquadra no problema. O problema não está na expressão, está em como está sendo manipulada no objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método `Regex.Match` só irá retornar a primeira ocorrência do que encontrou na entrada. Para obter todos os resultados, use o método `Regex.Matches`, no qual retorna todas ocorrências.

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var texto = "if(true) { {{palavra1}} + {{palavra2}}; }";
        Regex r = new Regex(@"\{\{[^\}]+?\}\}");
        var m = r.Matches(texto);
        foreach(var match in m)
            Console.WriteLine(match);   
    }
}
```

<sub>Veja funcionando no [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/QqLjol).</sub>

Documentação do [Match](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.match?view=netframework-4.8) e do [Matches](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.matches?view=netframework-4.8).